# 'thread' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, multithreading, compiler-errors

I am a newbie to c++. Currently I am learning how to use thread. However, I cannot build and run the program correctly using thread. The system keep giving me warning "'thread' was not declared in this scope". I am using Eclipse OXYGEN and MinGW with Windows 7.
I have searched for solution for an entire day.
I tried to select the dialect of GCC C++ Compiler as ISO C++11 and added "-std=c++0x" for the editor's discovery.
I also tried to add pthread in the library.
And I even reinstalled all the stuff, but neither of these help.

Below is the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
void task1(string msg){
    cout << "task1 says: " << msg;
}
int main()
{
    thread t1(task1, "Hello");
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

And the errors are:

..\main.cpp:10:5: error: 'thread' was not declared in this scope

..\main.cpp:11:5: error: 't1' was not declared in this scope

Any suggestion?Thanks a lot.

Comment: What version of GCC is this? Please be more specific about which software you're using.

Comment: Relevant: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/195639/17853

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18913542/560648

Comment: I am sorry that I am not familiar with the software! May I know where can I check the version of GCC?

Comment: I checked, it should be 6.3.0.

Comment: Give exact version numbers for all the named software.

Comment: Also read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30390278/560648

Comment: i followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037574/threads-in-eclipse-and-c11, but still not work.

Comment: That's for a completely different operating system. Did you read the pages I linked you to yet?

Comment: Yes. I think you pointed out the main problem. I used win32, which has no C++11 multithreading features. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Okay, good luck!